# Looking for batch script to monitor last modification date of files

Tags: windows, batch-file

My company has a lot of automation that runs overnight via batch scripts. Mostly just copying new files here and there. What I am looking for is a way to run a check of the file creation dates / last modification dates after all the scripts have ran to ensure everything is up to date. It would basically look to a specific file in a shared drive or UNC path. If that file is less than 24 hours old, do nothing. If the subject file is OLDER than 24 hours, then trigger an email. I already have a VBS to send an email so I could add that at the end of the IF statement. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the file *modification* date with `for %a in (file.txt) do echo %~ta` (double the `%` in batch files)

Comment: This is definitely getting me on the right track.  However, if I run the command in the batch file I do not receive a result.                                                             "for %a in (C:\PROJECTS\results.txt) do echo %~ta > C:\PROJECTS\NAVIS_MONITOR.txt".  If I copy and paste the string to a cmd prompt it works perfectly and then I can do a FC and get what I need.  But when I run that line out of a batch file, I don't get anything.

Comment: In a batch file `%%` must be written twice instead of just `%`. See the help on command `for` output on entering in a command prompt window either `help for` or `for /?`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This got me going.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways and means...

Here's a routine that will do something along the lines you outline:

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "runflag=runflag.###"
SET "foundrun="
ATTRIB -h "%sourcedir%\runflag.###"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%a IN ('dir /b /od /a-d "%sourcedir%"^|findstr /n /r "^"') DO (
 IF %%b==%runflag% SET foundrun=Y
 IF NOT DEFINED foundrun SET "$%%a=%%b"
)
(
 ECHO(Old file list
 FOR  /F "tokens=1,2delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO(%%b
)>"%sourcedir%\%runflag%"
ATTRIB +h "%sourcedir%\runflag.###"
IF DEFINED $1 ECHO(send email
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. `runflag` is simply a convenient filename.

The object here is to look for files that have not been updated since the previous run of this routine. This gets over the fixed "24 hours" idea - in case of holidays, weekends, etc.

The names of files that haven't changed would be in `runflag.###` - ideal for using in a mailer like `blat`.

I played around with the `hidden` flag here - to hide the file from "this shouldn't be here - I don't understand. I'll delete it". (those who take that attitude may often be defeated with a simple +H and +R). Improve or remove the ATTRIB commands as you will.

Answer (score 0):

Change `\\server\share` and use the filename in place of `filename.ext` and this should launch your `email.bat` file if the file is older than 1 day.

```
robocopy "\\server\share" "%temp%" filename.ext /minage:1 /L |find " New File " >nul && call email.bat
```